# Special character \x100E gets stripped while encoding android

Tags: java, android, json, string, spring-android

I am working on US Drivers License string. I get that string from `manatee scanning sdk`

The license string starts with format `@\n\x001E\rANSI 63601...` while encoding it to json (*json encoding is done internally by spring framework*) the special character `\x001E` gets stripped resulting in string something like this `@\n\rANSI 63601`

I tried to ASCII encode license string first by doing:

```
LicenseString = new String(LicenseString.getBytes(), "ASCII");
```

this does preserves `\x001E` but strips `\n \r` chars

resulting in string something like this `@\x001eANSI 630601...`

Can somebody guide me what am i doing wrong?

P.S: double escaping special chars etc is not an option for me here.

**EDIT**

I am working in Android Studio and i am storing the string `@\n\x001E\rANSI 63601...` in a Java `String` object

Comment: What you are calling a string doesn't look like text. Perhaps a Java or JavaScript `String` isn't the best datatype for it. They are both counted sequences of UTF-16 code units. "\x100E" is [not legal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) in Java and an escaped ␐ followed by "0E" in JavaScript. Please [edit] in a clarification.

Comment: @TomBlodget Made the edit. The data i am storing in string is returned by license scanning sdk in a `Java String` object.